# Collections - extracting from an array of strings in a dictionary

Tags: arrays, dictionary, collections, swift2

I have a large body of data that takes the following form: [Array of four integers], {Set of strings pertaining to that array of integers}. For example,

```
[1,1,1,8],{"(1+1+1)*8"}

[1,1,2,8],{"1*(1 + 2)*8","(1 + 2)/(1/8)"}
```

etc.

I have thousands of these pairs saved in an external text file, and need to be able to recall individual lines on the basis of the four integers in the key. One solution would seem to be to read the text file into a dictionary at launch time, but the obvious formulation for the dictionary

```
let myDict2:Dictionary<Array<Int>, Array <String>> = [[1,1,1,8]: ["(1+1+1)*8"],[1,1,2,8]: ["1*(1 + 2)*8","(1 + 2)/(1/8)"]]
```

fails because "Type 'Array' does not conform to protocol 'Hashable'."

But we can transform the key from an array of integers into a string, and try with this:

```
let myDict2:Dictionary<String, Array <String>> = ["1118": ["(1+1+1)*8"],"1128": ["1*(1 + 2)*8","(1 + 2)/(1/8)"]]
```

No error, and it even looks like we can extract a result with

```
let matches2=myDict2["1128"] // correctly returns ["1*(1 + 2)*8", "(1 + 2)/(1/8)"]
```

But when we try to pull an element from that answer with `matches2[0]`, we get `"Cannot subscript a value of type '[String]?'"`

Banging randomly on my keyboard, I got this to work with `matches2![0]` but I have no idea why.

1. Is there some way to make my original dictionary attempt [array of ints, set of strings] work?
2. In the second formulation [string, set of strings], Why does `matches2![0]` work and `matches2[0]` not?
3. Is a dictionary a reasonable approach to this, or is there some other data structure that might better accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will answer your second question first:

```
let matches2=myDict2["1128"] // returns an Optional<Array<String>>
```

Every `dict[key]` call will return an optional value because the dictionary may not contain that key. So you must unwrap it first

```
matches2[0]  // error
matches2![0] // ok
```

Now onto your other questions: a `Dictionary` is appropriate for cases when you must maintain uniqueness of data according to a key. For example, if every person requires a unique Social Security Number, the SSN should be used as a dictionary key and the person info as its value. I don't know what your requirements are so I will leave it generic at that.

Joining the four numbers into a string is a bad idea, unless all the numbers have the same number of digits. For example, `(1,23,4,5)` and `(12,3,4,5)` will produce the same string.

`Array<Int>` does not implement the `Hashable` protocol, so you must provide your own wrapper that does. This is my attempt:

```
struct RowID : Hashable {
    var int1: Int
    var int2: Int
    var int3: Int
    var int4: Int

    init(_ int1: Int, _ int2: Int, _ int3: Int, _ int4: Int) {
        self.int1 = int1
        self.int2 = int2
        self.int3 = int3
        self.int4 = int4
    }

    var hashValue : Int {
        get {
            return "\(int1),\(int2),\(int3),\(int4)".hashValue
        }
    }
}

// Hashable also requires you to implement Equatable
func ==(lhs: RowID, rhs: RowID) -> Bool {
    return lhs.int1 == rhs.int1
            && lhs.int2 == rhs.int2
            && lhs.int3 == rhs.int3
            && lhs.int4 == rhs.int4
}

let myDict: [RowID: [String]] = [
    RowID(1,1,1,8): ["(1+1+1)*8"],
    RowID(1,1,2,8): ["1*(1 + 2)*8","(1 + 2)/(1/8)"]
]

let id = RowID(1,1,2,8)
let value = myDict[id]![0]

// You can also access it directly
let value2 = myDict[RowID(1,1,1,8]]![0]
```

Comment: Because of constraints on the Integer array, I know there are no ambiguous entries if converted to string form. However, your example implementations of Hashable and Equatable will surely come in handy in the future. Thank you.